# TDD: How to create tests that tests init value

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tdd

I'm new to TDD and I've encountered a problem. As far as I know all tests in the TDD should fail before the production code is ready. I've developed the following code:

The Car interface:

```
public interface CarOperations{

/**
 * Return current car speed in km/h
 */
public int currentSpeed();

}
```

The Car class:

```
public class Car implements CarOperations{

@Override
public int currentSpeed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}}
```

JUnit test:

```
    @Test
public void testInitSpeed() {
    Car car = new Car();

    assertEquals(0, car.currentSpeed());
}
```

So I expect that this test will fail because every TDD test should fail before I develop any production code, but because of int default value this test will pass. I can change the method's return type to Integer and receive NULL value, but I want to know how to deal with primitives in such case? Maybe my test is wrong?

Comment: Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/224365/in-tdd-is-it-bad-practice-to-pass-a-test-with-code-that-would-pass-more-than-on - in my opinion such a trivial case is not an issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think such a trivial case is an issue as it's obvious that if you don't return 0 the test will fail. Now you could `return -1;` if you do want to confirm that the test can fail.

Comment: I know that this is rather an academic discussion than real problem, but when I change return value to -1, does it mean that I started writing production code? Because first I should write a test..

Comment: I don't know the academic answer, I only deal with real problems! ;-)

Comment: @woytech Or as proposed by somebody else: `throw new UnsupportedOperationException();`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when you write the test first, there should not be a class or properties defined. This means that the app fails to compile which counts as a test fail. Then you simply don't assign init values to the fields, and test will fail again.

P.S: Testing the default values of the type ( 0 for int for example, null for String etc) is kinda pointless.

Comment: regarding your P.S. I agree for such a simple example, but if the class becomes less trivial, testing that the default value is 0 (i.e. if the default constructor is used the variable does not get initialised) is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning default values (primitives or not), you could throw an exception (e.g. [NotImplementedException](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/NotImplementedException.html)). That way, your test will always fail.